# Javascript leaflet function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have a basic doubt on how can i refresh the content of some layer dynamically in the program. e.g.

```
function clicked() {
        this.options.style.fillOpacity=0.8;

        indiaLayer.redraw();

        }


        indiaLayer.on('click',clicked);
```

here i called indiaLayer on click. It got activated and then i changed some value inside the event listener function...so far so good..firebug shows that the value has actually changed. But i don't know how can i manifest the changes on the map. That is the map doesn't change. Which function should i use? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If indiaLayer is a TileLayer, you should use `indiaLayer.setOpacity(.8)`. If it's a Path (or an object that extends a path, eg. Circle), use `indiaLayer.setStyle({opacity:.8})`.